# transition top only works with transition all

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

Hello i have a Problem with transition top.

If i do it like this, it works:

```
.mb-navbarCollapse {
        width: 100%;
        top:0px;
        background-color: #515151;
        background-image: url('img/darkgrey-grid-pattern.png');
        background-repeat: repeat;

        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
```

But if i do it like this, transition top is not working:

```
.mb-navbarCollapse {
    width: 100%;
    top:0px;
    background-color: #515151;
    background-image: url('img/darkgrey-grid-pattern.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;

    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-image 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.1s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transition: background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

This is my nav:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top mb-bg-red mb-red-grid-pattern">
...
</nav>
```

maybe this information is important. I add my class **mb-navbarCollapse** to `<nav>` but i'm not removing the class **navbar** which look like this:

```
.navbar {
    height:64px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right:-30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Thanks for reading

EDIT: Harry's answer

Okay, i did this:

```
-webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 0s ease-in-out, background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 0s ease-in-out, background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 0s ease-in-out, background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 0s ease-in-out, background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 0s ease-in-out, background-repeat 0.1s ease-in-out;
```

Now top is working but background-image its also animated but i don't want to animate it :/

EDIT2: Demo http://mirsoftware.de/muthbau/

Comment: When you want to specify the individual properties, you should set them as comma separated values to same property. If you repeat the same property multiple times, the latest one would override the ones specified previously.

Comment: Hi harry, i edit my post, please have a look

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. If you don't want it to be transitioned/animated, why are you adding it there? Remove it.

Comment: i also removed it but its still animated :/

Comment: If that is the case, please create a demo for us to see and debug.

Comment: Can you work with this or do you need a jsfiddle demo? http://mirsoftware.de/muthbau/